# O365: Create or Share rules on public folder mailbox

Tags: office365, microsoft-outlook-2016, rules, public-folders

**Current situation:**

Our finance department uses a public folder which has mail enabled so they receive digital invoices on accounting@mycompany.net.

Every user has its own subfolder in which they drag their invoices so our automatic ocr-flow can process the invoices.

Some users are creating individual rules so the mails are automatically moved to specific folders.

**question:**

- Is it possible to either manage the rules for the public folder via the exchange admin panel, or via powershell?
- If not, is their a way to export/import the rules from one key user to other users?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can manage Inbox rules using PowerShell. Key cmdlets: [Get-InboxRule](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/mailboxes/get-inboxrule), [New-InboxRule](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/mailboxes/new-inboxrule). And you can create a PS script for deploying required rules for other users.

Comment: Thank you thims for your reply. Does this also work with public folders?

Comment: You can't have Public Folder rules even in Outlook. Or, if you mean specifying public folder as a target then, yes.